# angularjs ng-repeat selected option

Tags: angularjs

How to get the object of selected option in angular js using `ng-repeat`? Sample [fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/779pz05o/) where myself populating the dropdown as,

```
<select ng-model="id" ng-init="id = '-1'" ng-change="select(option)">
    <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
    <option ng-repeat="option in list" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
  </select>
```

If someone chose option with id=1, i want to get the object `{id:1, name:'A'` in `$scope` variable.

**EDIT:** Myself tried with `ng-options` but filtering is not happening as required based on previous dropdown selection. [sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/779pz05o/5)

Comment: Use `ngOptions` instead of manually repeating out the options. From the documentation: `ngOptions should be used when the <select> model needs to be bound to a non-string value.`

Comment: Correct.. But if I use `ng-options` filter won't working properly fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/779pz05o/5

Answer (score 1):

Use option object in ng-value={{option}} and whenever u select an option your scope.id will have the desired object.
Basically ur ng-model gets populated with selected value.

Answer (score 0):

Just you have to change your option to this

```
<option ng-repeat="option in list" value="{{'Id : ' + option.id + ' Name : '  + option.name }}">{{option.name}}</option>
```

Hope this will work for you and you were looking for the same result

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 option to get as Object.

**option 1** :

you can use Filter to get Object

```
<select ng-model="id" ng-init="id = '-1'" ng-change="select((list|filter:{id:id}))">
    <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
    <option ng-repeat="option in list" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

updated fiddler [here](https://jsfiddle.net/779pz05o/2/)

**option 2** :

set your value as Object (option)

```
<select ng-model="id" ng-init="id = '-1'" ng-change="select(option)">
    <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
    <option ng-repeat="option in list" value="{{option}}">{{option.name}}</option>
  </select>
```